# Move Coupon field

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

I have a coupon field in the **File path:** `/theme/template/checkout/onepage/progress.phtml`

**Code:**

```
<br><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?><br>
```

I wan to move this to: `/theme/template/checkout/onepage/onepage.phtml`

When I insert my code snippet in `onepage.phtml` it doesn't render. How do I make it render?

Answer (score 0):

please try to add below code in **`app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout.xml`** layout file,

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml">    
    <block type="checkout/cart_coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="checkout/cart/coupon.phtml"/>    
</block>
```

and than put the following code in `template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
```

**hope its work for you**

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have no checkout.xml in my theme. Where should it be?

Comment: its here  : app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout.xml ( base/default - theme name, if you are using another theme than check there. )

Comment: also i update path in my answer